# Twitter boostrap nav-collapse: multiple items on one line?

Tags: html, css, less, twitter-bootstrap

The responsive functionality of bootstrap's navbar is *awesome* but it is really aggressive about taking each individual item and placing it in its own line in the collapsed menu, for example:

```
            <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav pull-left">
          <li><a id="mpd_header_playlist" href="/">Now Playing</a></li>
          <li><a id="mpd_header_playlists" href="/playlists">Playlists</a></li>
      </ul>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Volume:</a></li>
            <li><a style="width:100px; valign:middle;"><div id="mpd_header_volume"></div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-step-backward icon-white mpd_previous_button"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-play icon-white mpd_play_button"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pause icon-white mpd_pause_button"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-stop icon-white mpd_stop_button"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-step-forward icon-white mpd_next_button"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Search Music</a></li>
            <li class="">
                <form class="navbar-search" id="search" action="search">
                    <input type="text" name="q" class="search-query" placeholder="Search Library..." />
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

produces a line in the collapsed menu for each and every `<li>` listed, when really, I'd like a line for the header and playlist links, and a line for all the icons that makeup the play controls.  Is there a way to "group" items so they are collapsed smartly by the responsive navbar?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever manage to get this sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to put your links in the same li element.

Comment: The issue with that is, that the items wrap within a single list item (despite application of text-wrap, white-space, etc. properties) - so the items don't look the same